# C# - Bitwise operations on large integers

Tags: c#, .net, bitwise-operators

I have many flags that I want to store them in an integer, so that later I can perform bitwise AND operation on them.
The number of these flags may be up to 1000. However, there are no types in C# that can store 1000 bits.

For Example, I want to perform (&) operation onü

```
100000010000000011100000000000000000000000000000...........00001 --> (1000 flags)
000000000000000001111110000000000000000000010101.......... 11111 --> (1000 flags)
```

So, how can I perform this (&) operation on a two bit collections?

Comment: Why do you want to store 1000 "flag" bits in a single integer type? Such a use-case is explicitly *not* an `int`

Comment: +1 because I don't think a downvote is warranted... OP is **improperly** using `int`s as `BitArray`s but that doesn't make the question invalid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I have many flags that I want to store them in an integer, so that later I can perform bitwise AND operation on them.

That's a non-sequitur. You can use [`BitArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) with its [`And`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.and.aspx) method to satisfy that requirement without *artificially* going via a numeric type.

If you haven't *logically* got a number (and "many flags" doesn't sound like a number to me) you shouldn't go out of your way to use a numeric representation.

Comment: +1 for idiomatic approach. Only use case I can imagine where this isn't the right approach is when you're working on a version of the framework (e.g. .NET Micro) where it's not supported. Even so, it's  not terribly hard to roll a custom `BitArray` class that mimics it's behavior.

Comment: Why is that a non-sequitur, Jon?

Comment: @Luke: Because you don't need to store them in an integer in order to do a bitwise AND later - you can use BitArray.

Comment: @Jon Thanks, in his defense he said he *wanted* to store them as integers. I've commented on the answer below. I think this answer is useful but is harder to implement in a wider context.

Comment: @LukePuplett: He said he wanted to store them as integers *so that he could later perform a bitwise AND operation on them*. That implies you need to store them as a number in order to do that - which you don't, hence it's a non sequitur.

Comment: @JonSkeet Okay fair enough. So the OP's general idea is sound, its just you were picking up on a subtlety in the language he used - that's fine.

Answer (score 3):

I guess [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) is what you are looking for. It has [`BitwiseAnd` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.op_bitwiseand.aspx)

Comment: +1 as this *will* meet the OP's request, but it still doesn't seem *correct*

Comment: This seems the simplest solution. It's easy to deal with numbers, store and serialize them. `BitArray.And` can work on arrays of different sizes which adds overhead, getting stuff in and out of one is a pain, too.